# Activity not opening on button press

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a basic android application with a client - server chat, a link to a website and on option to open a database (that I am yet to create). I have created a button to open the activity for the database but nothing happens when I press the button.

Here is my application main activity;

```
public class AndroidChatApplicationActivity extends Activity {

private Handler handler = new Handler();
public ListView msgView;
public ArrayAdapter<String> msgList;

// public ArrayAdapter<String> msgList=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
// android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    msgView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    msgList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    msgView.setAdapter(msgList);

    // msgView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgList.getCount() - 1);

    Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Send);

    receiveMsg();
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_inputText);
            // msgList.add(txtEdit.getText().toString());
            sendMessageToServer(txtEdit.getText().toString());
            msgView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgList.getCount() - 1);

        }
    });

    Button websiteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.website_Button);
    websiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendToWebsite();
        }
    });
}

protected void sendToWebsite() {
    String url = "https://www.ljmu.ac.uk/";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

    Button databaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.database);
    databaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AndroidChatApplicationActivity.this,
                    Database.class));

        }
    });
}

// receiveMsg();
// ----------------------------
// server msg receieve
// -----------------------

// End Receive msg from server//

public void sendMessageToServer(String str) {

    final String str1 = str;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // String host = "opuntia.cs.utep.edu";
            String host = "10.0.2.2";
            String host2 = "127.0.0.1";
            PrintWriter out;
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(host, 8008);
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                // out.println("hello");
                out.println(str1);
                Log.d("", "test");
                out.flush();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("", "test2");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("", "test3");
            }

        }
    }).start();
}

public void receiveMsg() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // final String host="opuntia.cs.utep.edu";
            final String host = "10.0.2.2";
            // final String host="localhost";
            Socket socket = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(host, 8008);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (true) {
                String msg = null;
                try {
                    msg = in.readLine();
                    Log.d("", "MSGGG:  " + msg);

                    // msgList.add(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (msg == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    displayMsg(msg);
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();

}

public void displayMsg(String msg) {
    final String mssg = msg;
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            msgList.add(mssg);
            msgView.setAdapter(msgList);
            msgView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgList.getCount() - 1);
            Log.d("", "Hi Test");
        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is my manifest;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.UTEP.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="androidChat.AndroidChatApplicationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="androidChat.Database" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

And here is database as it stands;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import edu.UTEP.android.R;

public class Database extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.database);
}

}
```

Comment: check device log, you might find the answer. Or post it here

Comment: You really shouldn't be setting the listener of your database button in sendToWebsite. There's just so much wrong with that in general and it may be the source of your issue. Try setting it in onCreate, you can control whether or not a user can interact with it by using setEnabled or setVisibility.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that "nothing happens", I'm assuming your button `clickListener` isn't even get called. Try moving this to your `OnCreate` method:

```
  Button databaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.database);
databaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(AndroidChatApplicationActivity.this,
                Database.class));

    }
});
```